# Can I use variable in python to extract data from Postgresql?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I'm writing a code from python to query data from my postgres database, here is the code:

```
cur.execute(
"""SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{"2016-08%' """)
```

In my query, I will gradually increase the month ascendingly as to 2016-09, 2016-10...2017-01..2020-11..
I wonder if is there a way to insert a variable, say like:

```
year =  2016
month = 09
```

and in the for loop every time the year and the month increase by 1, but since this code is inside the cur.execute select statement, I'm not sure how to do it...any ideas? Thanks!

also, if is possible, can someone please let me know how to do the same thing for the output csv file's name.

```
df.to_csv('201610_tesla_cooments.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Just use [placeholder values](https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way. It is a little tricky because you have curly braces in the base part of the query, so I just split it into two variables so that it was easy to use the Python format function:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format

## Code:

```
query_base = """SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{"""
query_date_form = "{year}-{month:02}%'"

start_year = 2017
start_month = 11
end_year = 2019
end_month = 5

year = start_year
month = start_month
while True:
    if year == end_year and month > end_month:
        break

    if month > 12:
        year = year + 1
        month = 1
        continue

    query_date = query_date_form.format(year=year, month=month)
    query = query_base + query_date
    print(f"Execute this: {query}")

    month = month + 1
```

## Execution:

Just update this with your code.

```
(venv) [ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ python sql.py
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2017-11%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2017-12%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2018-01%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2018-02%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2018-03%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2018-04%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2018-05%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2018-06%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2018-07%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2018-08%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2018-09%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2018-10%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2018-11%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2018-12%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2019-01%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2019-02%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2019-03%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2019-04%'
Execute this: SELECT id FROM reddit_tesla_title WHERE created_time like '{2019-05%'
```